# How do I make my input buttons look well in most browsers?

Tags: styles

Is there a way to make my input buttons prettier? They looked wonderful on Chrome but then I checked them on Firefox and IE and they look like Windows 98. Right not I'm using any styling at all and they look more or less like Google inputs (no surprise I suppose) I'd be really happy if they all looked like they do on Chrome if there is any way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inspired by someone else's button style while you are in Chrome, right click that button, select **Inspect element**

Answer (score 0):

You could always use CSS to spruce them up ... or use an image for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 and play with shadows and round corners but this is not supported in IE<9. Standard buttons looks different in every browser/OS.